# Speed up Reaver attack on router

Tags: wifi, wps, reaver

I am trying to get the WPS pin by [Reaver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/reaver-wps/) attack.

The code I run is

```
reaver -b (bssid) -c (channel) -i wlan0mon -vv
```

It takes too much time guessing the WPS pin because it starts counting from 0000****.

The router I am trying to hack is TP-Link and I also know that the WPS pin starts with 7. Can I speed up my attack by commanding Reaver to start testing the numbers that start with 7?

Is there anything else I can do to speed up my attempt?

Answer (score 3):

When you run Reaver it creates a session file in the current folder to allow you to resume in case the execution gets interrupted. You can run reaver to create the session file, stop it then edit the session file. The very first line contains the pin it was at when stopped.

Change that to the PIN value you want to start at (like 70000000). Then run reaver again with your parameters. It will ask you if you want to resume the session. Say yes and proceed.

Alternatively you can add `-s <session file>` to your parameters and it will resume the session automatically.